# Вопрос по QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, cmd

Мне нужно реализовать работу с терминалом из приложения.Задача состоит в том что бы через `ssh` на сервер кидать проект,компилить его там,и возвращать обратно.
У меня не получается общаться из приложения с терминалом `cmd.exe`. 
Вот мой пример кода:

```
 QProcess *gzip = new QProcess();

gzip->start("cmd");

gzip->waitForStarted();

gzip->write("cd C:\Intel\Logs \r\n");

gzip->write("dir \r\n");

gzip->closeWriteChannel();
gzip->waitForFinished();

ui->textEdit->setText(gzip->readAllStandardOutput());
```

Т.е в идеале мне нужно подключится к серверу,и дальше уже выполнять команды по типу `pscp`,`chmod`,`qmake`.. и все это в одной сессии . Как реализовать это?

@UPDATE
Команды через QProcess получилось выполнять,но ssh не хочет конектится

```
QProcess* gzip = new QProcess(this); // local variable works

gzip->start("powershell");

gzip->write("ssh usir@192.168.1.242\n");//коннект

gzip->write("1\n");//пароль
gzip->write("ls\n");

gzip->closeWriteChannel();
gzip->waitForFinished();

ui->textEditNormal->setText(gzip->readAllStandardOutput());
ui->textEditError->setText(gzip->readAllStandardError());
```

Код перестает выполняться после `gzip->write("ssh usir@192.168.1.242\n")`,до ввода пароля не доходит.
Если в ручную то пишу `ssh usir@192.168.1.242`,дальше пароль и все готово.Как исправить мою проблему?

Comment: Вроде понял в чем была проблема,заэкронировать забыл